# page floating left in ie

Tags: html

I have this code,I don't know why in ff it's looks ok and the page is in the middle,but in ie the page is floating left.
I guess it's got something to do with the #wrapper,but I can't figure it out.
I tried to put  after each "article" div,but that didn't help also.
thanks for helping.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css" />
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <!--  refresh the page with jquery !-->
       <script type="text/javascript">   
             $(document).ready(function() {      
             $('#Button_refresh').click(function() {     
             location.reload();}); }); 
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
    <button type="Button" id="Button">Home</button> 
  <h1>My Special Big Header</h1>  
  <button type="Button" id="Button_refresh">refresh</button> 
  <div class="article1" id="article1">
    <?php require_once('connection.php'); 
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)){'<div class="article1" id="article1">';echo '<h1>'.$nt['name'].'</h1><br />'.$nt['article_text'].'</div>';}
    ?>
  <div class="article2" id="article2">
    <?php 
        while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result2)){'<div class="article2" id="article2">';echo '<h1>'.$nt['name'].'</h1><br />'.$nt['article_text'].'</div>';}
    ?>
          <div class="article3" id="article3">
    <?php 
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result3)){'<div class="article2" id="article3">';echo '<h1>'.$nt['name'].'</h1><br />'.$nt['article_text'].'</div>';}
    ?>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css:

```
 body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:11px; 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    /* backcolor fade with css3 */
    background: #FEFBE6;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FEFBE6, #F2DD45);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FEFBE6, #F2DD45);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#FEFBE6, #F2DD45);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#FEFBE6, #F2DD45);
    background: linear-gradient(#FEFBE6, #F2DD45);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FEFBE6', endColorstr='#F2DD45');
}

#wrapper {
    width:960px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#4D0000;
 }
 #article1,#article2,#article3
 {
    width:920px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#87CEEB;
    margin-bottom:20px;
 }
#Button_refresh{

    float: right;

}
#article1
{

    margin-top:45px;
}
```

Comment: Post the content of design.css

Comment: not sure if its the reason but you seem to be missing a few </div> tags

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to add a doctype, this should go right at the top of your document:

```
<!doctype html>
```

Then you need to validate the HTML output to make sure there are no obvious errors, try using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

If the results of those two steps don't fix your problem then you need to look in design.css for a CSS error of some kind.

Comment: I added the <!doctype html> and that solve the problem! thank you so much James